# How to prevent calzones from getting soggy on steam table?

Tags: storage-method

How do i keep fresh made calzones from getting soggy while displayed on a steam table?

Comment: What time frame are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no good answer to keeping calzones dry and crisp on a steam table, even if you wrapped it in foil.  You may need to look at other equipment, such as heat lamp, food warmer or a food merchandiser/heated display (eg Pie, pizza display box )